# How to rebase the changes locally?

Tags: git

I'm getting this error while merging the changes:

```
The change could not be merged due to a path conflict.
Please rebase the change locally and upload the rebased commit for review.
```

I think it occurs when the same file is modified by two different changes.
But I don't know how to rebase the changes locally.

Comment: Are you asking how to do rebase in general?

Comment: yes, how to rebase the changes locally? @abhinav

Answer (score -3, accepted):

First of all understand the concept of rebase from [git scm book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

You can also use rebase on your local commits by issuing this command

git rebase -i COMMIT_IDENTIFIER

The above command will open up a text editor to change, reorder or edit your commits later than and including the COMMIT_IDENTIFIER.

I have written a small blog about git rebase [here](http://abhinavpachauri.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/falling-in-love-with-git-rebase/)

Comment: Hi,I tried your code but it gave me this error
    `$ git rebase -i COMMIT_IDENTIFIER
    fatal: Needed a single revision
    invalid upstream COMMIT_IDENTIFIER`

Comment: Linked blog is not available anymore :-(

Comment: Linked blog is broken.